# Manually route traffic

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application where I need to sometimes manually route traffic between pods. I have deployment and a service which exposes certain port to the world. Using deployment, I'm creating 2 replicas of the application and traffic balances well between them, but can I manually define which connection should route to certain pod? If it does matters, an applications are listening for UDP connection on certain port.

Let's summarise: for now I have one deployment which creates 2 replicas of my application and one service which exposes certain port to the world. I'd like to be able manually (using script or etc.) route traffic between these replicas. What should I do? Is this possible?

The main goal is I still need to have only one port exposed to the world and all the magic should be behind the doors.

I'm new to Kubernetes and it may be an easy task, so any documentation link or direct example will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How easy is it to decide where the traffic goes?  You probably need two separate Deployments and two separate Services for this; potentially you could configure a service mesh like Istio for this, or implement your own proxy, maybe based on Nginx or Apache or another gateway product.  At a high level this doesn't sound like something Kubernetes does on its own.

Comment: @DavidMaze probably it will be based on external client IP, which can be stored anywhere: on external db (outside the cluster), redis or something.

Comment: ? A Service alone does not expose your port to the world if you use type ClusterIP. Also please provide a little more detail. What you want to do definately does not sound like best practice and we might be able to help you better if we knew what you were up to